# What does it mean in C++? int *p=(int*)(&a+1)

Tags: c++, pointers

while studying c++ interview problem, I was stuck in the question below:

What's the output to the code below?

```
int main()
{
  int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int  *p=(int*)(&a+1);

  cout<<*(a)<<endl;
  cout<<&a<<endl; 
  cout<<&a+1<<endl; 
  cout<<(*p)<<endl;
  cout<<(*p-1)<<endl;
  cout<<(*p-3)<<endl;
}
```

the output is

```
1
0x16fdff450
0x16fdff464
1
0
-2
```

I am wondering why *p is 1, can someone share the idea?

thanks!

The explanation of

```
int  *p=(int*)(&a+1);
```

Comment: It means undefined behavior. Why is the C++ code tagged with C?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  `p` doesn't point to any `int` object.

Comment: Remember how pointer arithmetic in C++ works: adding an integer to a pointer operates in units of the type pointed to.  `a` has type `int[5]`, so `&a` is a pointer to an array of 5 ints.  Thus `&a+1` points to the *next* array of 5 ints. This would make sense if it were part of a 2-dimensional array, but it is not, so it's pointing to garbage.  Casting to another type just makes things worse.

Comment: It means someone is trying todo too low level stuff in C++. Direct pointer arithmetic in C++ is hardly ever needed because it often leads to bugs (like undefined behavior when accessing data out of bounds). Instead of integer array try the same with [std::array<int>::at(-1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at).

Comment: This link seems relevant here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: To make `p`a useful pointer, it should rather be initialized like `int  *p=(int*)(&a[0]+1);`. This way it would use the correct type and navigate inside the array when adding/subtracting integers.

Answer (score 3):

`int  *p=(int*)(&a+1);` is undefined behavior. This is because `(&a + 1)` effectively shifts the pointer from the address of a by `sizeof(a)` (that's what the +1 does). Now the pointer is pointing to the beginning of another array of the same size as a, but not a, and not a memory location that we are actually sure is the memory of a new array. Therefore the reason `cout << (*p)` outputs 1 must be just because 1 happens to be the value at the memory address directly after the array a.

Comment: *“Therefore the reason `cout << (*p)` outputs 1 must be just because 1 happens to be the value at the memory address directly after the array a.”* No, that would actually be *defined* behavior. Because the code results in *undefined* behavior, the compiler is free to generate whatever code it likes for the reads outside of the array `a`, it doesn't have to generate instructions to read from memory right after `a` at all.

Comment: @G.Sliepen -- "undefined behavior" means **only** that the C++ language definition doesn't tell you what the code is supposed to do. It's certainly a reasonable speculation that there's a 1 at the address directly after `a`, and that's what the output shows. That's what would happen with any reasonable code generator; there's no reason for the compiler to go out of its way to generate code that deliberately does something silly. Sure, that's not required, but that's the point of the circumlocution "must be just because"; don't read too much into that.

Comment: You must forget about what you think is a "reasonable" when it comes to undefined behavior. The compiler is free to do many things that are all reasonable in some way. For example, it might decide that adding 1 to `&a` results in a pointer to undefined memory, so it will just not add `1`, and thus dereference the original array. Or it could decide that the lines that print anything that is out of bounds shouldn't happen, so it could eliminate the print calls. What UB will do will also vary wildly with compiler and optimization levels.

Answer (score 0):

The program has **undefined behavior** because you're *typecasting* a pointer of type `int(*)[5]` to an `int*` and then dereferencing that resulting pointer. Basically you're treating the resulting pointer as if it was pointing to an integer.

Undefined behavior means anything can happen(allowed to happen as far as the c++ standard is concerned) including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.